# Quiero hacer una lista de usuarios en un archivo de texto pero quiero que mi codigo reconozca a los usuarios

Tags: python

Mi codigo es muy simple; Básicamente lee un archivo de texto "test.txt" y luego lo imprime al usuario. Luego el programa pide un usuario nuevo para agregar a la lista. Lo que quiero que haga mi programa es que si se inserta un usuario que no esta en la lista agregarlo y si es un usuario que ya esta adentro de la lista dar un el siguiente mensaje "bienvenido + usuario"

```
#Open test.txt
users = open("test.txt",'r')
#Read and Print "test.txt"
with open('test.txt', 'r') as reader:
    print("Users: " + users.read())
#Input will be written in "test.txt"
Log = input("Write your user: ")  
#Write in test.txt
with open(('test.txt'), 'a') as writer:
    writer.write("\n" + Log)
#Close test.txt
users.close()´´´
```

Comment: Y bien, ¿cuál es tu pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes leer el archivo y cargarlo en memoria, por ejemplo en una lista y comprobar si el nombre está o no en la lista o bien puedes mover el cursor del archivo y leerlo dos veces, una para imprimir y otra para buscar:

```
with open('test.txt', 'a+') as file:
    file.seek(0)  # Cursor al inicio del archivo
    print("Usuarios", file.read())

    # Input will be written in "test.txt"
    log = input("Write your user: ")  

    file.seek(0)
    for line in file:
        if log == line.rstrip():
            print(f"Bienvenido {log}")
            break
    else:  # Si el usuario no se encuentra (ciclo completado sin break)
        file.write(f"\n{log}")
```

La primera línea, `users = open("test.txt",'r')` no sirve para nada, abre el archivo en modo lectura pero nunca lo usas.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo que para guardar los nombre utilices el módulo csv, acá te dejo un enlace: [Cómo leer y escribir con csv](https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/how-to-read-and-write-csv-files-in-python--cms-29907)

no soy experto en python pero podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
import csv


def updateUsers(list_users):
    with open('users.csv', 'w') as myFile:
        writer = csv.writer(myFile)
        writer.writerows(list_users)  
    print("Writing complete") 


def readUsers():
    list_users = ''
    with open('users.csv') as myFile:
        reader = csv.reader(myFile, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            list_users += row[0]

    return list_users


list_users = readUsers();

user_name = input('cuál es tu nombre? ')

if user_name in list_users:
    print('Bienvenido usuario')
else:
    list_users += ',{}'.format(user_name)
    updateUsers(list_users)
```

Para terminar tendrías que crear el archivo 'users.csv' para que python lo lea. Te recomiendo leer algo de documentación.